# What does the B in King Torture's soldiers' forehead stand for?

Tags: samurai-flamenco

In episode 8, some of King Torture's monsters appeared. They were always accompanied by some soldiers with a B on their forehead:

[image: One of King Torture's soldiers]

What does this B stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In episode 9, we get a better look at the soldiers:
[image: The Torture Boys!]

Here, besides the B on their forehead, we can see a T on their belts.
Also, earlier that episode (around minute 2), the Branding Piranha calls out the soldiers by yelling "Come on, Torture Boys!":
[image: The screaming Piranha]

So, **the B most likely stands for Boy(s), as in Torture Boy(s).**